# Clarification about software update

Tags: updates, update-manager

I'm using ubuntu 15.04

I have a really slow internet connection and I have to update my ubuntu because it has never been updated since I installed it.

I'm new to ubuntu and my question is:

does the software update keep downloaded files and packages if the connection was lost?
does the update process (download and update) have to be in one continuous session?
how can I list the downloaded packages and files for software update on my computer?
can I download an off-line update package (.deb .gz or whatever) and where?
what can I do to successfully update ubuntu while having an unreliable connection?

an answer to any of these questions would help a lot

thank you very much and I hope I'll be helping other ubuntu users in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does the software update keep downloaded files and packages if the
>   connection was lost?

There are two cases:

1. If the connexion is interrupted during the downloading then after restarting the downloading process later it will continue normally if the files are not corrupted/altered.
2. In case some of the downloaded files are altered during the transmission (downloading) process, then you need to read and follow this official documentation: [PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure)

> does the update process (download and update) have to be in one
>   continuous session?

No. Not necessarily but:

1. Do not stop the downloading process by yourself
2. If your connexion is slow you are a little bit more prone to see errors during the transmission (downloading) process.

> how can I list the downloaded packages and files for software update
>   on my computer?

Launch the Dash and search for Update Manager to see if there are updates to install:

[image]

If you do not launch the Update Manager, it will prompt itself each time there are new updates to ask you whether you want to update your packages or not.

> can I download an off-line update package (.deb .gz or whatever) and
>   where?

Yes. Depending on your version and release, you may search for the packages on [Ubuntu Packages Search.](http://packages.ubuntu.com/)

> what can I do to successfully update ubuntu while having an unreliable
>   connection?

You may choose the package you want to update/install and download it somewhere (cybercafé, or using your university's Wi-Fi ...)  and [install it offline](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Answer (score 6):

The package manager will first download all packages into the folder `/var/cache/apt/archives/` before the installation of the packages starts. Packages that are already there will not be downloaded again.

If the package manager gets interrupted during downloading it will just continue if you start it again (but if you interrupt it once it started installing packages that may cause problems).

For offline updates see [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Comment: I tried updating using terminal by executing

sudo apt-get update

but then I realized it only updates packages already installed
I therefore executed

sudo apt-get upgrade

which I suppose downloads and installs new packages
however, during execution it outputs

get # : sy.archives.ubuntu..... libg6 ... 

and downloads this package
when I run it again it shows this again and downloads it again
what is going on here?

Comment: sorry for the bad format -_-

it writes all lines as a single line -_-

Comment: @AliA.Ismaeel  the format is so because you are supposed to add information to your question, not using the comments that are short communications.  And it seems that your comment here is really another question.